# I need to extract strings from a cell in google sheets.. I'm trying to use the rexectextrac function, but strings are separated with ""

Tags: google-sheets

This is an example of the information i get when reading a QR

```
{"ver":1,"date":"2021-07-07","name":123456,"line":12)}
```

What I need to extract is

```
2021-07-07
123456
12
```

Name length is not always the same.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=regexextract(A2, "^.*(\d+).*(\d+).*(\d+)")`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest approach to understand, supposing that your raw data runs A2:A, would be to place the following in B2 (for instance) of an otherwise empty B2:D range:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"date...(.+)...name..(.+)..line..(\d+)")))`

Individual periods mean "any one character" and `.+` means "any group of one or more characters.

`\d+` means "any group of one or more contiguous digits.

Sets of parentheses within the double quotation marks are *capture groups*, meaning "return this part."

If you want the returned numerical values to be *numbers* instead of strings (i.e., a real date and numbers that can be used immediately in comparison or math operations), then use this version:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,".+date...(.+)...name..(.+)..line..(\d+).+","$1~$2~$3"),"~")))`

This will return your date in raw format (a number in the 40000 range, representing the number of days elapsed since December 30, 1899). Just format that range/column as **Format > Number >** *date format of choice*.